# Cleaning AD Accounts and Exchange mailbox

Tags: active-directory

Well the Problem is actually quiet simple, though i believe the solution is not.

There is a Training Room, that emulates the "real World". After each Training period, we would like to reset all the Training accounts to a "Factory Reset" so all the stuff the Trainees have done, does not matter. Since the AD account is connected with lync and Exchange, i believe it is not wise to just delete the ad account and make a new one.

And the next Problem is, since it is a clone of the System / configuration used for real, we cannot Play arround with virtual machines that much.

Thanks for your help and advices.

Shinji

Comment: Hi and welcome to the stackexchange comunity. Please keep noted that the StackOverflow comunity is mostly for Develper questions where your question might be better over at ServerFault. I will vote for a migration here as you might get better answers from the Admins on ServerFault then the Developers on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell to build a script which can do that. So for example after the training is finished (e.g. manually or automatically via an task scheduler and a user who have rights):

1. Let the script delete the AD account(s) (with [Remove-ADUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617206.aspx)) which will remove the Exchange Mailbox and any Lync / Skype for Business feature.
2. Let it [wait some time](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177002.aspx) so that the change can sync across the environment
3. Let the script create a mailbox ([new-mailbox](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997663(v=exchg.160).aspx)) including lync features ([Enable-CsUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398711.aspx))

Note:
Keep noted that you might also wish to delete the local OS profile here

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want to clean up all the Account without removing and re-creating the user.

The cleanest way to do this is removing the user and re-creating it.

Any other way will involve that you login into the user and clean up manually all the things into outlook (folder by folder) and skype for business.

Or try to code something to look for folder by folder and do the cleanup.
Here's how to read the inbox folder (WellKnownFolder.Inbox)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324732/ews-only-reading-my-inbox